# Django not returning queryset despite using get,filter and all

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

Please I am a beginner and I'm trying to make a Hospital Management System.I want to display the Patient profile however it is only returning the first name in my queryset. I need all the data saved to my database displayed.I've tried filter, get and all.They return only the first name as defined in my **str** method.

#### Views

```
def ProfileView(request):
    profile = Patient.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'profile':profile})
```

#### Models

class Patient(models.Model):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
email= models.EmailField(unique=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

#### Profile.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block content%}
<div class="container">
  {{profile}}
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

#### Result that displays in html

```
<QuerySet [<Patient: Kehinde>]>
```

Comment: you have to loop through results if you are looking to get always only one result use .get() and not .filter()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system

Answer (score 1):

You probably want One-to-One relationship between Profile and User instead of doing lookup through email

Other than that [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) returns `QuerySet` while [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) returns instance so you should iterate through results with `.filter()`

```
def ProfileView(request):
    profiles = Patient.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profiles':profiles})


{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block content%}
<div class="container">
{% for profile in profiles %}
  {{profile.first_name}}
  {{profile.last_name}}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

You could use `.get()` if you are expecting just single object as result

```
def ProfileView(request):
    profile = Patient.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile':profile})
```

Comment: I'm sorry. But why does my {{profile.first_name}} not work?

Answer (score -1):

In your html:

`{{profile}}`

displays profile.**str** because it's the human readeable of the instance.

if you want the patient's first name: `{{ profile.first_name }}`

Comment: I've tried it didn't work. Thanks. You just opened my eyes to other possibilities